# What can an adventuring group do to protect their items/money while questing?

Tags: magic, medieval

I'm starting a new adventuring group with my friends. I live in a fantasy world with predictable levels of danger in certain areas. We're part of an adventuring guild. Everyone in our group has a different "role", and each person in the group is theoretically replaceable. We're splitting the profits as evenly as we can.

We can accept quests from any town, but most quests, we've found, are located a day's travel or further away from one. We don't have horses, for monetary reasons, hence our long travel time and being forced to carry our belongings on us.

The problem is when we're about to enter a dangerous situation, where one or more of us could be left behind. **Ideally, we only want to bring the items that are necessary with us into these situations, but we don't have a good place to store the items and money.** We could split them between ourselves, but then if someone gets left behind, then as a group we lose that portion of our loot as well.

**Why not use a bank of some kind?** Or create a home base? Well, because the quest locations are spread so far out, if we were to store things in one place it's likely we would often need them in another. A day's travel or more just to get the items we need is a PITA.

**With all of that in mind, what can we do with our valuables before entering a dangerous situation?** Can you help my adventuring party solve this logistical nightmare?

---

Note: Obviously, storing our valuables needs to be in a way that someone else can't just come along and find them and take them for themselves. We trust each other, but quests are public information, so leaving our stuff lying around is just asking to have it be stolen.

Note: Magic exists in our world. In fact, we currently have two mages in our group (a damage dealer and a healer). However, our spells are simplistic and tend to be solely in those two categories. Enchanted items are also very uncommon and tend to be expensive (usually out of our price range). We would prefer answers without magic, if possible.

Note: Tag help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Please understand that our goal at WB.SE is to help you develop consistent rules for your world.  A world can be of any size, but the closer that "size" comes to individual people, the more dependent the rules become on the context of your story.  There comes a point where we're no longer worldbuilding (where many stories can take place) but storybuilding, which isn't what we do.

Comment: Should I have formatted the question in a different way? I was just trying to make it more interesting. I'm actually looking for a wide range of answers because there are many adventuring parties in my world and I was having trouble coming up with ways for them to realistically hang on to their valuables in dangerous situations. I intend to have the main party in my world learn the best ways from other parties, up until they can afford something better. I don't really see how this *isn't* a world building question, unless it was just the formatting...

Comment: Regrettably, formatting isn't the problem.  Think about it this way.  Worldbuilding is the process of describing *systems.*  People may be involved in some of those systems (e.g., a bureaucracy), but it's not the people you're building, it's the system.  Here at WB.SE, the moment you ask about the actions or behavior of people (not systems), you begin running the risk of being too story-based (and almost always will be).  The smaller the number of people you're asking about, the more TSB the Q is.  Ask about a single individual and you're storybuilding, not worldbuilding.  (\*continued\*)

Comment: In the case of this question, you're not asking about a system (worldbuilding). You're asking about the actions or options available to individuals (storybuilding). Rather than asking about rules that would be applied to your characters, your asking how your characters would react... to what? And that's the problem. You're on-topic when you ask about how individuals would react to the rules of your world. You're off-topic when you ask about how individuals react to circumstances in your world. Systems vs. stories. (\*continued\*)

Comment: Finally,  consider your comment, "...to learn from other parties...."  In that one comment, you made my point.  Your party isn't learning from the rules of your world, they're learning from circumstances within your world.  That's storybuilding.  It's a somewhat ruthless definition, but it's there for a purpose.  [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  But the moment we start helping people past what is essentially writer's block, a discussion is what we're having. (\*OK, sorry, one more continued\*)

Comment: Finally, finally, don't pass up the opportunity to use [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), especially the [Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), it's frequently haunted by many of our most active participants, and chat is where discussions belong.  There, you can ask pretty much anything you want.

Comment: @JBH Thank you very much for the in-depth description of where I went wrong. Honestly I really wouldn't have gotten it without that. I did read through the question linked in the "on hold" banner and the culture link and still couldn't figure it out. FYI I've also been reading Worldbuilding questions on this site for literal years (in Hot) (ie long time reader, first time asker). I was very confused in that my question didn't feel different from what I had read, but I get it now. Next time I have a question like this I'll try chat ;)

Answer (score 7):

Delegate the task of logistics and safeguarding items for the group to an outside individual or individuals that are not expected to enter dangerous situations.

They would travel with the group, and would be in charge of things outside of simply carrying stuff, such as cooking, setting up camp at night, stuff like that. However they would stay in a safe location outside of the confrontation area in dangerous situations. This doesn't mean that they are unskilled in combat though. If someone attacks your stuff while your main group is away, someone needs to protect and/or move your stuff.

As for why they would do all these menial tasks for you, they would recieve their share of the reward as any other member of the group would upon completion of the task.

Comment: An adventuring *guild* does imply a certain level of structure, with "apprentice", "journeymen", and "master" adventurers. This sounds like the perfect job for apprentices: important enough to pay someone to do, relatively safe, and plenty of opportunities to train with the senior members during downtime.

Answer (score 5):

The usual trick is to hide it. Stick it in the bushes, in a backpack up a tree or just bury it.

Unless you're being spied up at the exact time, chances are nobody would ever find it.

If you bring magic into it, you then can make it invisible, use portable secure shelters or extra dimensional spaces and even magical guard creatures.

Comment: I just figured I should note somewhere that we've done this before and lost some items... We're a bit forgetful. A comment is better for this because it's kind of embarrassing...

Comment: Exactly, this is after all where all those hidden treasures come from in the next round of play.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is in your answer. **You can't be the only adventuring group with this problem. And you are part of a guild.**

If the guild has places all over, then they likely have **a designated quartermaster/goodsholder that keeps items for adventurers in many of the places and towns.**

You pay a small fee and they keep it for you, for a contracted amount of time. The way they likely make the most money is this: dead adventurers.

Basically, you pay for a certain amount of time--if you want you can pay for up to a year's time in advance, as a deposit, but you only have to pay for the storage time that you use. Unclaimed items that are left past the deposit time go back to the guild/ quartermaster. The guild has enough of a rep that thieves stay away. It's a good payday, but the guild has hired magic users in the past to track down any thieves, so while most times there isn't anything better than a sturdy door and lock, it's not a good idea for a thief to try it.

For this to work, there has to be a guild rep in nearly every town, or someone that they entrust.

**The guild can also supply you with a low-level lackey who doesn't have the chops to truly adventure, but does work as a hireling.** Again, because it's via the guild, the guild has a vested interest in tracking down any hireling that steals from the group. They'll be loyal insofar as they are paid. They will either be paid straight, or can get a smaller percentage from the group. Ideally, they wear some sort of sigil of the guild letting people know who and what they are.

Outside the guild there's always **the stash** basically, you look for a likely place to hide your goods. As this is common, it's kind of fun to find something already there, as the last adventurers to die here did the same dang thing, but did not survive to pick their stuff back up. This serves as foreshadowing, and might have some useful stuff for players as they need.

Answer (score 3):

- Buy a [manor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manor) and appoint a [steward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steward_(office)). After all, [real estate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/real%20estate) is the only real worth. If they are not yet that rich (you mentioned the inability to afford horses), start small and buy a peasant hut. Then buy another.
- Ask mum and dad to safeguard it. For that matter, a dutiful child would give a large percentage of their loot to their family.
- [Breaking the fourth wall](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreakingTheFourthWall), it is difficult to get all the players together for each session. So turn that into an advantage. The guy/gal who has to study for an exam or babysit younger relatives is always "guarding the baggage." It is a genre convention that these "zombie player characters" will not be attacked by NPCs while they keep out of the action. Everybody wins.

Answer (score 1):

#### Dig a hole

If you have a shovel, it doesn't take too long. If you have a nice burlap sack, your stuff won't get dirty in a day or two. As long as there is nothing that smells good to badgers in the hole, no one will disturb it.

#### Leave someone outside

Do you have someone who couldn't make the raid? Then he/she is hanging out, right outside the instance, with all your loot.

#### Hire a lackey

Honestly, if you have that much stuff to truck around, hire a man to do the job for you. This (honest?) fellow can be left in the nearest settlement while you enter the Dungeon of Earnest Regret.

#### Hire (buy) a donkey

Much like hiring a lackey, except it is acceptable to tie the lackey/donkey to a tree to ensure he/it doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Have the healer carry the most valuable items**

As a healer, they are the least likely to be left alone if the group has to split, and also supposedly less exposed in combat.

Comment: But the healer is also the weakest of the group. If he goes down (and the healer goes down easily) you've lost everything. I'd be for digging a hole